# Guess File Type Windows Similar to Linux `file`

Tags: python, file, types, mime

Is there an equivalent to the Linux `file` command on Linux? I would prefer something with Python bindings, but anything will do as long as it can be accessed through a DLL or launched a subprocess.

Comment: file or find? what are you looking for?

Comment: Is cygwin acceptable, or do you need native commands?

Comment: @Ekkehard file. Editied the post.

Comment: @syrion I would much prefer native. I use Cygwin myself, but I do not want it to be a dependency for what I am working on.

Comment: Googling a bit found this: http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/File-identifier-Download-17009.html  But I'm not sure of the license (or reliability) of the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) doesn't need Cygwin. `file` includes a (BSD licensed) library and Python bindings for it.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I will use since the program needs to work on Linux and Windows anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native function in Windows, but you can use [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html). This tools has been around since 2003 and still gets maintained.